# How can I convert char* to char[] in C and then add it in an array without problem?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I know some similar questions already exists but they did not help me in my case.

What I need to do is creating a table symbol for a compiler project using flex. Basically, I get a `char*` (a new identifier to add to the table symbol) that is then placed in a `char[1000]` array, that is my table symbol.

Everything works fine until I try to print my table symbol (called symbArray): when I'm trying to print `symbArray[4]` for ex., it also prints me `symbArray[5]` and `symbArray[6]`, ... At this point, if you have any solutions, I'll take it.

What I tried to do to solve it is to use `strcpy(intermediaryVariable, yytext)` to convert my `char*` (called yytext) into a `char[100]` (intermediaryVariable). But this does not seems to work because now, `symbArray[4]` = `symbArray[5]` = `symbArray[6]` (see details later).

Here is my function that should add the symbol to the table after that I tried to solve the problem with strcpy():

```
void addSymbole(char text[100], int index) {
    // findSymboleArray is a function to verify if our identifier does not already exist
    // symbArray is the symbole array declare on a global scope as char* symbArray[1000];
    if (findSymboleArray(text) == -1 && symbArray[index] == NULL) {
        char textToCopy[100];
        strcpy(textToCopy, text);
        symbArray[index] = textToCopy;
        printf("%s goes to index %i.\n", text, index);
    }
}
```

Here is how I call my function addSymbole()

```
// newChar is the intermediaryVariable declared on a global scope as char newChar[100];
// symbArrayLength is declared as int symbArrayLength = 0; on a global scope too

strcpy(newChar, yytext);
addSymbole(newChar, symbArrayLength);
symbArrayLength += 1;
```

And here is how I print the content of my symbol table:

```
void printSymboleArray() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        if(symbArray[i] == NULL) {
            // so that the for-loop can be stopped
            i = 1000;
        } else {
            printf("value of element at index %i: %s.\n", i, symbArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a part of result that I can get when I print the symbol table:

```
value of element at index 0: main.
value of element at index 1: char.
value of element at index 2: int.
value of element at index 3: float.
value of element at index 4: A878U_GH.
value of element at index 5: A878U_GH.
value of element at index 6: A878U_GH.
value of element at index 7: A878U_GH.
```

with symbols that are:

```
coucou
bogoss13_
BAD_CHAR
A878U_GHJ // note that in the result, the J is not printed and is sometimes replaced by random characters like '3' or 'c' for example when retesting the program
```

so that the expected result is:

```
value of element at index 0: main.
value of element at index 1: char.
value of element at index 2: int.
value of element at index 3: float.
value of element at index 4: coucou.
value of element at index 5: bogoss13_.
value of element at index 6: BAD_CHAR.
value of element at index 7: A878U_GHJ.
```

Please note that main, char, float and int are initialized with this function:

```
void initializeSymboleArray() {
    // reserved names
    symbArray[0] = "main";
    symbArray[1] = "char";
    symbArray[2] = "int";
    symbArray[3] = "float";
    symbArrayLength = 4;
}
```

To sum up, I would like to know how to properly convert a char* into a char[] so that such a problem that I get (all the elements in the indexes are equal to the last identifier detected) does not appear.
If there is another solution than converting a char* into a char[], I would be glad to hear it.

I hope this isn't too much confusing and I apologize in advance for the lack of clarity.
Thank you for reading me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`printf("%s", str)` will print byte sequence pointed to by `str` until it reach a null (`"\0"`) symbol. So my educated guess is, your original problem was because you did not null-terminated your strings. The `strcpy` function will automatically null terminate the result (as stated in the [manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html)).

Your new solution has a memory management issue. In `addSymbole` function you define a buffer called `textToCopy` then use strcpy to place the string in that buffer. Afterwards you proceed and add a pointer to this buffer in your table (`symbArray[index] = textToCopy;`). Because this buffer is allocated on the stack, it would be poped (removed) when the function returns (the buffer gets out of scope). So the pointer is no longer valid.

I guess the reason why you see all the indexes have the same value is because the same memory is reused when you again call the `addSymbole` function. You can verify this by checking the memory address (`print("%p\n", &symbArray[i])`).

You can use `malloc` for reserving some memory on the heap. When you allocate memory from heap it would stay there until you explicitly free that (using `free` function).

If I want to modify your code I would rewrite your `addSymbole` function like shown below.

```
void addSymbole(char text[100], int index) {
    // findSymboleArray is a function to verify if our identifier does not already exist
    // symbArray is the symbole array declare on a global scope as char* symbArray[1000];
    if (findSymboleArray(text) == -1 && symbArray[index] == NULL) {
        char *textToCopy = malloc(100); // allocate a buffer with enough size.
        if (!textToCopy) { // If malloc failed to reserve memory it returns NULL
            // Hanlde the error here
        }
        strcpy(textToCopy, text);
        symbArray[index] = textToCopy;
        printf("%s goes to index %i.\n", text, index);
    }
}
```

I also want to warn you about the line you are copying `yytext` to a buffer. `strcpy` copies characters of the string until reaching `"\0"`.

```
strcpy(newChar, yytext);
```

If `yytext` is not null-terminated then it would cause issues. You could at least use `strncpy` so that your `newChar` don't overflow.

```
char *strncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n);
```

Comment: as I see you do not care if malloc succeeded

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this. It is important to check if malloc succed.

Comment: Thank you for this answer that worked for me. Also the advice about strncpy is useful. I can not upvote your answer because I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

UB (undefined behaviour). You assign `symbArray[index] = textToCopy;` pointer with address of the automatic variable `textToCopy` and this variable stops to exists when the function returns.

```
char *addSymbole(const char *text, const size_t index) 
{
    if (findSymboleArray(text) == -1 && symbArray[index] == NULL) 
    {
        symbArray[index] = malloc(strlen(text) + 1);
        if(symbArray[index])
        {
            strcpy(symbArray[index], text);
        }      
        printf("%s goes to index %i.\n", text, index);
    }
    return symbArray[index];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I can not upvote it because I do not have enough reputation. The code did not worked for me (warning: passing argument 1 of ‘findSymboleArray’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
   78 |     if (findSymboleArray(text) == -1 && symbArray[index] == NULL) but you pointed out a good problem in my code with your comment.

Comment: @Bliscor68 It should be `findSymboleArray(const char *)` - it is called const correctness. If you do not change the parameter - make it const